# r - What is the error in this code to repool/change range

Tags: r, range, multiple-columns, lapply

I want to repool all items for a specific scale except WB01_08 and WB01_10.
I want to change the range for the items: "WB01_01", "WB01_02", "WB01_03", "WB01_04", "WB01_05", "WB01_06", "WB01_07", "WB01_09", "WB01_11", "WB01_12", "WB01_13"
1 should become 6, "2"=5, "3"=4, "4"=3, "5"=2, "6"=1.

The code below works: No error message. 6 becomes 1, 5 becomes 2, and 4 becomes 3 as wanted.
However, a 1 does not become a 6. The range for the repooled columns WB01_01, WB01_02, etc. is no longer 1-6 but 1-3.
Can you help me what I did wrong, please?

```
myfun <- function(z, lookup) {
  for (nm in names(lookup)) {
    z <- ifelse(as.character(z) == nm, lookup[[nm]], z)
  }
  z
}
neu_ba_data[cols_to_change] <- 
  lapply(neu_ba_data[cols_to_change],
         function(x) myfun(x, c("1"=6, "2"=5, "3"=4, "4"=3, "5"=2, "6"=1)))
```

Comment: Could you share a little bit of sample data to illustrate the problem? Just a few rows and 2 columns should be plenty. You can use `dput()` to make a copy/pasteable version of your data in R, `dput(neu_ba_data[1:10, cols_to_change[1:2]]) would give the first 10 rows of the first 2 `cols_to_change`. That will help us test and debug your function on real data. (Pick rows that include a "1" so the issue is present in the sample data.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be more straightforward to do as math than as an iterative lookup. We can subtract the current value from 7 to get the result:

```
neu_ba_data[cols_to_change] <- 
  lapply(neu_ba_data[cols_to_change], function(x) 7 - x)
```

If you had a more complex case where a lookup is necessary, you need to make changes in one pass---I think the problem with your code is that the first step changes 1 to 6, and the last step changes 6 to 1, undoing the first step.

Here are couple options:

```
# using dplyr
library(dplyr)
neu_ba_data = neu_ba_data %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(cols_to_change),
    recode, `1` = 6, `2` = 5, `3` = 4, `4` = 3, `5` = 2, `6` = 1
  ))

# using base R
neu_ba_data[cols_to_change] <- 
  lapply(neu_ba_data[cols_to_change], function(x) {
    as.numeric(as.character(factor(x, levels = 1:6, labels = 6:1)))
  })
```

Note that all of these are untested, but I think they should work